# Jmeter - Want redirected URL to be displayed in response data as its giving response code 302 in response header

Tags: jmeter

I have generated a jmeter script.
But I'm not getting anything in response data (View tree listner).
I'm getting Response code: 302 and Response message: Moved Temporarily in response header (View tree listner) also giving the URL to which it is redirected in Location field in response header.
I want this redirected URL to be[image] displayed in response tab.

[the url i wnat in response data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRanR.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRanR.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the URL using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Field to check: `Response Headers`
   - Reference Name: JMeter Variable name of your choice, i.e. `location`
   - Regular Expression: `Location: (.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image: Regular Expression Extractor Location Header]
3. You will be able to access the extracted URL as `${location}` or `${__V(location)}} where required.

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) article for more information on correlating dynamic values in JMeter test.